# What does the term " Juju trunk" mean

Tags: juju

In the juju documentation on writting a charm, [link](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/write-charm.html) a prerequisite is being in the "juju trunk." Is this a specified location in my system after having installed the juju packages, or is this a environment I create myself. ALso, What other prerequisites do I need to be aware of when I attempt to build a juju charm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That wording is a bit confusing. What they mean is that you should be in the the root directory of juju's source branch. So:

```
$ bzr branch lp:juju
$ cd juju/
```

This is more of an assumption than a prerequisite. It seems to me that the only reason why this is "required" in the example is so that the paths in your commands match the paths in the example commands. Like this one from the "Test run" section:

```
$ juju deploy --repository=examples local:oneiric/mysql
$ juju deploy --repository=examples local:oneiric/drupal
```

If you're not in "juju trunk" you could rewrite that as:

```
$ juju deploy --repository=path/to/repo local:oneiric/mysql
$ juju deploy --repository=path/to/repo local:oneiric/drupal
```